# can you analytically solve this bayesian hierarchical model - bernoulli trials

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, bernoulli-distribution

Is it possible to analytically solve (i.e., use a conjugate prior) the hierarchical model shown in the image below to obtain the posterior distribution.  The data are composed of bernouli trials sampled from different groups.  The image is taken from http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2011/08/extrasensory-perception-esp-bayesian.html

My data are similar to the data discussed in the blog post but I have a *ton* of data.  I figure that if there is an analytical solution, it would be much more feasible to apply a bayesian hierarchical model to my data.  Plus, I am simply just interested in peoples' answers.

[image]

Comment: By solve do you mean obtain the posterior distribution, do Bayesian inference, or get a MAP estimate?  For inference the answer has to be no.

Comment: And how big is your data?

Comment: Hey, I want to obtain the posterior distribution and get the MAP estimate.  Not sure how you could get a posterior and not be able to use bayesian inference...

Comment: Bayesian inference, at least to me, means taking an expected value from the posterior.  This often does not have a closed analytical form.